# Use imfilter (matlab) in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, filter

i have a matlab code with an imfilter. Now i want to convert it to c++. I read this [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/8783/implement-imfiltermatlab-with-opencv/)
But i can't implement the filterEngine with openCV3.3 (there is no filterEngine anymore).

That is the filter in matlab:

```
imfilter(im2double(image),k,'same','replicate');
```

That is my kernel k:

```
k = fspecial('disk',3)
```

The result of this line is a 7x7 matrix with values between 0 - 1.

So the filter gets an input image. This has values between 0 and 1 (im2double). So I have to convert my 8bit image to this range, I think it works like this:

```
cv::normalize(inImage,outImage,0,1,cv::NORM_MINMAX);
```

Then the image is filtered with the kernel.
Finally I want to output an 8bit image again.

**So I want to convert the two given Matlab lines to C++.**

I read in the link that you cannot simply use filter2D.
But how can i do that? has anybody an idea?

**++++ Edit ++++** (testing Code snippet from zteffi)

I have tested the code.  The result is a different one so far.

The structure of the kernel "disk" wis a bit different (more zeros). the values in it are also different than in Matlab.

Matlabkernel:

```matlab
0   0.000280919186665314    0.0110250278796606  0.0171905962763014  0.0110250278796606  0.000280919186665314    0
0.000280919186665314    0.0245167426505023  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0245167426505023  0.000280919186665314
0.0110250278796606  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0110250278796606
0.0171905962763014  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0171905962763014
0.0110250278796606  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0110250278796606
0.000280919186665314    0.0245167426505023  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0353677651315323  0.0245167426505023  0.000280919186665314
0   0.000280919186665314    0.0110250278796606  0.0171905962763014  0.0110250278796606  0.000280919186665314    0
```

c++ kernel:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0.0303030303030303, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0;
 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303;
 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303;
 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303;
 0, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0.0303030303030303, 0, 0, 0]
```

I don't know how the values are calculated in matlab.

The following line should be create a "circle" of values in tha matrix.
But in the row dimension there are 3*2 zeros on the edge and in the column dimension 2 *2 zeros. But there should be only one zero in each corner.

```
Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(radius * 2 + 1, radius * 2 + 1));
```

Comment: So this is not close enough, but earlier you replied to an answer that “imfilter has over 400 lines of code. The effort is to high for this problem. I think it is ok to get a result close to the original filter.” Do what is it? Something similar that is easy, or something even closer that is hard? Or are you hoping someone else will implement this for you???

Comment: No, nobody has to implement that for me. When I see other contributions here, I always have the feeling that many people know the answers without having to program much themselves.(Simply by experience) I was hoping for that. I don't want to cause a lot of effort to anyone here

Comment: i hardcoded the kernel now, thats okay

Comment: Matlab's version uses anti-aliased circle. You might try OpenGL or some other library. `cv::circle` doesn't work even with `cv::LineTypes::LINE_AA` flag unfortunately

Comment: Wolfus, hard-coding the kernel is a very good solution.

Comment: sounds sarcastic. For the thread this is not the best solution, but I had limited time to solve that and the kernel always stays the same size (in my code)

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent of `fspecial('disk',3)` would be `cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(radius * 2 + 1, radius * 2 + 1))`, divided by the sum of the kernel, so the total sum is equal to 1. So something like:

```
Mat m = cv::imread("lena.jpg");
int radius = 3;
Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(radius * 2 + 1, radius * 2 + 1));
double sum = cv::sum(cv::sum(kernel))[0]; // use cv::sum twice to get sum of all elements
kernel.convertTo(kernel, CV_64F, 1 / sum);
cv::filter2D(m, m, CV_64F, kernel);
m.convertTo(m, CV_8U);
```

You don't need to convert the image into <0, 1> range unless you need to display it. You also don't really need to convert it into double in this case and swap the last two lines for:

```
cv::filter2D(m, m, CV_8U, kernel);
```

Comment: I will test it the next days - thank you for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tested your Code but the results differs. I edited my original Post with the results

Comment: Why  to use CV_64F - is this not too large? Or does this have any other benefit ?

Comment: I don't think difference in precision between `CV_64F` and `CV_32F` would be noticeable in this case, I used double to match matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You can see matlab's implemrntation of functions by clicking right mouse key on function name in editor and select "open 'function name' " item in menu.  It will show matlab code for the function, and you can port it accurately to C++.

Comment: Thats not what i want - the im filter has over 400 lines of code. The effort is to high for this problem. I think it is ok to get a result close to the original filter